# Why the getdata sub brings over values like F1, F2 instead of empty cells?

Tags: vba, excel, copy

Example of code

```
Sub getLookup()
  GetData "\\myserver\SourceFile.xls",  "2015", "A3:AW4", Worksheets("Lookup").Cells(3, 1), True
 end Sub
```

I use the getdata several times to copy a range of data from a closed workbook to my current workbook and it seems to work fine for me in Excel 2010 except for this particular range on my source spreadsheet "2015", the getdata returns the actual values from the source file and for cells that are empty (B3, D3, F3) , it returns values like F2, F4, F6 .... The digits appear to be corresponding to the column numbers. I check the source file (in sheet "2015", row 3) cell B3, D3, F3 appear to be empty.

It even shows F1 on cell (4,A) where the source file has an actual value in that cell. What are those F1, F2, F4, F6 ? Where do they come from?

Randomly, it appends a digit like 1, 2, 3 to a couple values on the destination sheet too. Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Thank you,

Here is the sub GetData (- that works but with some strange F1, F2, F4 values..)

```
Sub GetData(SrcFile$, SrcSheet$, SrcRange$, rTgt As Range, fHdr As Boolean)

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim a&
Dim cnct$
 'Initialize a variable for the connection string
  cnct$ = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)}; DBQ=" & SrcFile$
 'Initialize connection object
  Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
  With cn
    'Open the database connection
    .Open cnct$
    'Execute the query
    Set rs = .Execute("[" & SrcSheet$ & "$" & SrcRange$ & "]")
  End With
  'Initialize a variable for the upper left cell of the target range
  Set rTgt = rTgt.Cells(1)
  With rs
    'Determine whether to get the field header
    If fHdr Then
    'Loop across the fields
      For a& = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
        'Get the field names
        rTgt.Offset(0, a&).Value = .Fields(a&).name
      Next a&
      'Advance the target pointer to the next available row in the destination worksheet
      Set rTgt = rTgt.Offset(1, 0)
    End If

    'Apply the CopyFromRecordset method
    rTgt.CopyFromRecordset rs
    'Close the RecordSet
    .Close
  End With

  'Close the database connection
  cn.Close
  'Recover memory from object variables
  Set cn = Nothing
  Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you're getting default field names.  Does the Workbook in question have a header row?

Comment: No, the source workbook doesn't have a header row.  And those values F1 etc must be the default field names then because they only appear on the first row of the pasted range.  The weird thing is randomly the digits (that corresponding to the column order) get appended to some cells that have values. For example, if the source cell on column B has the value "NO", then on the destination cell, the value becomes "NO2".  My work around for this issue is to extend my copied range 1 row above.  The first row copied over now has all the F1, F2 etc but the below rows are usable for me.

Comment: Well, my workaround doesn't work well since a couple cells I need don't have the copied values.  Anybody knows if there is a better get-data sub out there to copy range of data from a closed workbook to the current workbook?